# The study of directional derivatives for functions that are minimums of convex functions

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

Has there been any research  on the topic of directional derivatives of functions that are minimums of convex functions?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. You may want to have a look at the Lagrangian relaxation as it works with subgradient direction to optimize the LR dualized function and can be applied on the convex problem. Also, this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4315743/595412) might be interested.

Comment: How can functions be minimums of convex functions? Can you provide an example of what you mean by this?

Comment: Say `z^k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{+\infty}` is a given convex function for each `k=1,\dots,K.` And, let `z:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{+\infty}` be defined as follows: `z(x) = \min_{k=1,\dots,K} z^k(x).` Intuitively, the directional derivatives of the function $z$ at point $x$ in direction $d$
 should match the directional derivatives of the function $z^k$ at point $x$ in direction $d$, where the function $z$ and function $z^k$ coincide at point $x$ (or where the function $z^k$ is active at point $x$). I am seeking a formal proof of this concept in the literature.

Comment: @SamiraFallah please [edit] the question to include your updated information. You'll get better answers than having your update sit in the comment section.